# How do I wrap text within a link tag using JavaScript/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my current code:

```
<a class="mg_label_7" href="/" shape="">Hello</a>
```

I want to have:

```
<a class="mg_label_7" href="/" shape=""><div id="hello">Hello</div></a>
```

So I can manipulate the background of the link text without changing the rest of the link areas text. Is there anyway to pinpoint this piece of text and insert a div or even a span using JavaScript/jQuery?

I've been trying to do this for around 3 hours, the closest I've got to achieving it is using

```html
 var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];

 var html = elem.innerHTML;

 elem.innerHTML = '<div class="red">'+ html + '</div>'
```

which successfully targeted a link in my code and changed it to the span, but if I try to getElementsByTagName then getElementByClassName and use mg_label_7 it won't work. There are duplicates of the tag in the code and I want to target all of them.

I'm trying to manipulate a SharePoint web part so I'm not sure if it's stopping it from being edited.

Comment: Are you looking to wrap *just* the word "Hello" when there might be more text? If not -- if you want to wrap *all* text in the link -- consider just adding an extra class to the `a` tag and styling that class.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I've edited it to show what I've tried so far and made it a bit more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.wrapInner()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/)

```
$('.mg_label_7').wrapInner('<div id="hello"></div>')
```

Comment: That's correct answer thought could be problematic regarding duplicate IDs if more than one element with class `mg_label_7`, but this is quite out of the question's scope

Comment: @A.Wolff I totally agree.  There's a lot of assumptions going into the example provided (only one `.mg_label_7` will ever exist.  The unique ID is required for whatever reason.  javascript maybe?), but this is closer to the OP's code in the question.  I tend to try to keep it as close to the original as possible

Comment: It's not working for some reason - it works with another similar instance on the page but not the one I want. There are multiple elements with mg_label_7 and I want to target all of them, could that be why it's not working?

Comment: @Emma That would be correct.  You can't have multiple elements with the same ID in the same document.  You will probably have to use a class instead: `$('.mg_label_7').wrapInner('<div class="hello"></div>')`

Comment: @JosephMarikle It's still not appearing for some reason. Another thing I thought is that because the HTML is generated by the JavaScript I'd have to make sure the code is executed after the elements are generated since it's a SharePoint web part. Do you know if there's anyway to ensure this?

Comment: You will have to make sure that the script with the wrapInner function is loaded after the others.  It's a good idea to wrap it in a `document.ready()` if it has to be included in your `<head>` tag.  Preferably, you should have jQuery, your other scripts, and your script that injects the class loaded at the end of the document before the closing `</body>` tag in that order.